# Get recipient voice during call for AI callbot

Tags: python, php, twilio, voice, twilio-twiml

I am working on the callbot.

What i need is to get the Realtime recipient's response (not complete call recording)

I am using Twilio for call.

Is there any way to get the Realtime response of recipient.

Example

```
Bot: Hello
Recipient: Hello Who is speaking?
Bot: I am Adam from any company.
Recipient: Why you are calling me?
```

let say call is continue but to answer the query of recipient i need what he speaks.
Recommended technologies are php and python.

I tried many solutions from Twilio but no success.
Gather verb
Record verb (record verb is recording the whole conversation instead of recipient voice).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in [the TwiML documentation for the Record verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record) that indicates it will do anything other than provide a recording of the entire conversation. However, it does provide the ability to [transcribe](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#transcribe) the callback. Perhaps that it what you need instead.

Finally, please keep [the legal implications of call recording](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#legal-implications-of-call-recording) in mind as you're developing your solution.